# Java Pattern match

Tags: java, pattern-matching, quantifiers

I've a long template from which I need to extract certain strings based on certain patterns. When I went through some examples I found that use of quantifiers is good in such situations.For example following is my template, from which I need to extract `while` and `doWhile`.

```
This is a sample document.
$while($variable)This text can be repeated many times until do while is called.$endWhile.
Some sample text follows this.
$while($variable2)This text can be repeated many times until do while is called.$endWhile.
Some sample text.
```

I need to extract the whole text, starting from `$while($variable)` till `$endWhile`. I then need to process the value of $variable. After that I need to insert the text between `$while` and `$endWhile` to the original text.
I've the logic of extracting the variable. But I'm not sure how to use quantifiers or pattern match here.
Can someone please provide me a sample code for this? Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a rather simple regex-based solution here with a Matcher:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\$while\\((.*?)\\)(.*?)\\$endWhile", Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(yourString);
while(matcher.find()){
    String variable = matcher.group(1); // this will include the $
    String value = matcher.group(2);
    // now do something with variable and value
}
```

If you want to replace the variables in the original text, you should use the [Matcher.appendReplacement()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement%28java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String%29) / [Matcher.appendTail()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendTail%28java.lang.StringBuffer%29) solution:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\$while\\((.*?)\\)(.*?)\\$endWhile", Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(yourString);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while(matcher.find()){
    String variable = matcher.group(1); // this will include the $
    String value = matcher.group(2);
    // now do something with variable and value
    matcher.appendReplacement(sb, value);
}
matcher.appendTail(sb);
```

Reference:

- [Methods of the Pattern Class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pattern.html)
  (Sun Java Tutorial)
- [Methods of the Matcher Class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/matcher.html)
  (Sun Java Tutorial)
- [Pattern JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)
- [Matcher JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html)

Answer (score 0):

public class PatternInString {

```
static String testcase1 = "what i meant here";
static String testcase2 = "here";

public static void main(String args[])throws StringIndexOutOfBoundsException{
    PatternInString testInstance= new PatternInString();
    boolean result = testInstance.occurs(testcase1,testcase2);
    System.out.println(result);
}

//write your code here
public boolean occurs(String str1, String str2)throws StringIndexOutOfBoundsException
    { int i;
      boolean result=false;


      int num7=str1.indexOf(" ");
      int num8=str1.lastIndexOf(" ");
      String str6=str1.substring(num8+1);
      String str5=str1.substring(0,num7);
      if(str5.equals(str2))
      {
          result=true;
      }
      else if(str6.equals(str2))
      {
          result=true;
      }

     int num=-1;
      try
      {
      for(i=0;i<str1.length()-1;i++)
      {    num=num+1;
           num=str1.indexOf(" ",num);

           int num1=str1.indexOf(" ",num+1);
           String str=str1.substring(num+1,num1);

           if(str.equals(str2))
           {
               result=true;
               break;
           }



      }
      }
      catch(Exception e)
      {

      }


     return result;

     }
```

}